# Компиляция в Visual Studio 10

Tags: exe, visual-studio, c++, компиляция

Подскажите как правильно скомпилировать приложение, созданное при помощи конструктора форм в VS10, **чтобы оно запускалось на машинах где нет студии**. Я так понимаю в код программы должны записаться все используемые библиотеки. После того как в настройках проекта поставил **Use MFC in a Static Library** ничего не изменилось, правда выдало ошибку *Command line error D8016: '/clr' and '/MT' command-line options are incompatible* после этого в настройках поставил **Runtime Libary: Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)**. Вообщем я нуп и мне нужна помощь :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чей именно конструктор форм? Для `WinAPI\MFC` или для Windows Forms? Судя по ошибке ты используешь `C++\CLI`. С ним нельзя использовать статическую линковку. Только динамическую.

Если ты в самом деле пишешь, используя Windows Forms, то лучше используй C#. Он больше для этого предназначен и там нет никакой библиотеки, требующей Visual C++, которую нужно линковать.